# Linux command to find directories where numerical directory

Tags: linux, shell

I have a directory structure like `/store/hour/`....

so example: `london/04/`...

I want to do a day to date report, so say:

show me all directories where the hour is <10 for example

How would I do this in a single command?

Thanks

Comment: `for p in /path/to/folder/{3..5}`

Comment: Probably `{00..09}`. Mind that this is bash-only though. If you want it more portable: `for p in /path/to/folder/\`seq -w 00 09\``

Comment: Filesystem is not SQL. 
If you need "reports" and with custom inputs, use SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing a `/store/hour` structure with 2-digit hours, a simple way can be to filter them with `egrep`:

Hour < 10:

```
ls -1d /* | egrep '^\/\w+\/0[0-9]$'
```

Hour < 15:

```
ls -1d /* | egrep '^\/\w+\/(0[0-9])|(1[0-4])$'
```